# Return a list from list.forEach with Java Streaming API

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a POJO:

```
class MyObject {
   private Double a;
   private String b;

   //constructor, getter + setter
}
```

Some function is creating a list of this POJO. Some values for `a` might be null, so I want to replace them with 0.0. At the moment I am doing it like this.

```
public List<MyObject> fetchMyObjects(Predicate predicate) {

     List<MyObject> list = getMyListsOfTheDatabase(predicate);

     list
       .forEach(myObject -> {
           if (myObject.getA() == null) {
               myObject.setA(0.0);
           }
     });

    return list;
}
```

Is there a way to integrate the forEach in the return? Something like

```
 return list
         .stream()
         .someStatement();
```

It's not about, if this is the best place to convert the nulls to zero, but rather a questions to better understand the streaming api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return the same `List` instance with a single statement, but you can return a new `List` instance containing the same (possibly modified) elements:

```
return list.stream()
           .map(myObject -> {
               if (myObject.getA() == null) {
                   myObject.setA(0.0);
               }
               return myObject;
           })
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`peek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#peek-java.util.function.Consumer-) function

> Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream, additionally performing the provided action on each element as elements are consumed from the resulting stream.

```java
public List<MyObject> fetchMyObjects(Predicate predicate) {
    return getMyListsOfTheDatabase(predicate)
            .stream()
            .peek(it -> if(it.getA() == null) it.setA(0.0))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: this is a very very bad advice. `peek` might not be executed at all in this case, since there is no need for it

Comment: Could you explain why?

Comment: run `Stream.of(1,2,3,4).map(x -> {System.out.println(x); return x + 1;}).count()` in java-9. Same thing goes here, all you care about in this stream is a List that is computed based on the  `getMyListsOfTheDatabase`; but you are not changing the input in any shape or form, thus `peek` may be thrown away entirely.

Answer (score 2):

While others have been happy to answer your question as it stands, allow me to step a step back and give you the answer you didn’t ask for (but maybe the answer that you want): You don’t want to do that. A stream operation should be free from side effects. What you are asking for is exactly a stream operation that has the side effect of modifying the original objects going into the stream. Such is poor code style and likely to confuse those reading your code after you.

The code you already have solves your problem much more nicely than any combined stream pipeline.

What you may want to have if you can modify your POJO is either a constructor that sets `a` to 0 if `null` was retrieved from the database, or method that does it that you may call from `list.forEach`:

```
    list.forEach(MyObject::setAToZeroIfNull);
```

> It's not about, if this is the best place to convert the nulls to
>   zero, but rather a questions to better understand the streaming api.

That’s fair. In any case I will let this answer stand for anyone else popping by.

Comment: Thanks for the post, very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you should be using `List::replaceAll`:

```
list.replaceAll(x -> {
    if(x.getA() == null) x.setA(0.0D);
    return x;
})
```

Comment: What would be the advantage over `list.forEach()`? (It seems to me that this is just more wordy/less readable.)

Comment: @OleV.V. I guess you are right, it's just my habit here

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` doesn't have a return value, so what you might be looking for is `map`

```
return list
    .stream()
    .map(e -> {
        if (e.getA() == null) e.setA(0d);
        return e;
    })
    .whateverElse()...
```

Answer (score 0):

The following would be fine:

```
list.stream()
    .filter(obj -> obj.getA() == null)
    .forEach(obj -> obj.setA(0.0));
return list;
```

However in your case just returning a Stream might be more appropriate (depends):

```
public Stream<MyObject> fetchMyObjects(Predicate predicate) {
     return getMyListsOfTheDatabase(predicate);
}

public Stream<MyObject> streamMyObjects(List<MyObject> list) {
     return list.stream()
         .peek(obj -> {
             if (obj.getA() == null) {
                 obj.setA(0.0);
             }
         });
}
```

I personally never used `peek`, but here it corrects values.

On code conventions, which are more string in the java community:

- Indentation: Java took 4 as opposed to C++'s 3 as more separate methods,
  and less indentation was expected. Debatable but okay.
- For generic type parameters often a single capital like `T, C, S`.
- For lambda parameters short names, often a single letter, hence I used `obj`.